# c++ get the last (n) char in a string

Tags: c++, string

i have a string and i want to get, for example, the position of the last (.) in the string, or whatever char i want to check, but untill now i just get a headeach.

thanks

Comment: Show us your code so far.   What works, and what do you need help with?

Comment: sorry i'm late to answer your comments, but i had some conection issues for all over a day, thanks to all for the answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is [find_last_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) what you need?

```
size_type find_last_of( const basic_string& str, size_type pos = npos ) const;
```

> Finds the last character equal to one of characters in the given character sequence. Search finishes at pos, i.e. only the substring [0, pos] is considered in the search. If npos is passed as pos whole string will be searched.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a guess.

Comment: Seems like a pretty good guess to me. Can't do much more than guess with this question.

Answer (score 18):

```
string lastN(string input)
{
     return input.substr(input.size() - n);
}
```

Comment: Where does N comes from?

Comment: that's unacceptable. input.size() could be less than n.

Comment: @karlphillip from the question. n means how many characters from the end of the string you want

Answer (score 7):

If your string is a char array:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 char buf[32] = "my.little.example.string";
 char* lastDot = strrchr(buf, '.');
 printf("Position of last dot in string: %i", lastDot - buf);
 return 0;
}
```

..or a std::string:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 std::string str = "my.little.example.string";
 printf("Position of last dot in string: %i", str.find_last_of('.'));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<stdio.h>` is nonstandard. Use `<cstdio>`. Same for `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   #include <string>
    /**
    * return the last n characters of a string,
    * unless n >= length of the input or n <= 0, in which case return ""
    */
    string lastN(string input, int n)
    {
        int inputSize = input.size();
        return (n > 0 && inputSize > n) ? input.substr(inputSize - n) : "";
    }
```

Comment: Why not return input if its length is less or equal to n?